# -[NSString sizeWithFont:] returns different results in release and debug builds

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uilabel, sizewithfont

I've used this code to resize a `UILabel`'s frame height to fit dynamic text several times with success:

```
(...)
CGSize labelSize = [thelabel.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

All was well until I started to build my apps using the iOS5 SDK.

For armv6 devices (iPhone3G/-), when building for debug, the label size is okay, but when building for release, the height value retrieved is the same as the width. I am running both of these builds on an actual device.

example with following log line:

```
NSLog(@"labelSize: %f %f", labelSize.width, labelSize.height);
```

output:
iphone3G - debug >

> Thu Nov  3 18:22:50 unknown appname[1071] : labelSize: 115.000000 19.000000

iphone3G - release >

> Thu Nov  3 18:22:50 unknown appname[1071] : labelSize: 115.000000 115.000000

Can anyone help or provide me with another solution to adjusting `UILabel`'s height based on the text length?

I'm aware there are some similar questions about this method, but they do not address this particular issue.

Comment: How are you setting up `constraintSize`?

Comment: I'm using the initial width and a high value:
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.

If you follow the link supplied by vfonseca, you arrive at: [Is there a way to compile for ARM rather than Thumb in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390606/is-there-a-way-to-compile-for-arm-rather-than-thumb-in-xcode-4)

And the selected answer tells you how to add the correct compiler flags to prevent this. Alternatively upgrade to Xcode 4.3 which has fixed this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't managed to understand the problem.

Although, replaced the UILabel resize method with an alternative way:

```
//init and store initial rect
CGRect initialLabelRect = CGRectMake(2*kMargin, auxHeight , 200, 0 /*will be overriden*/);
UILabel *dataLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:initialLabelRect];
dataLabel.text = @"long text here";
[dataLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:15]];          
//fit size will adjust both width and height, but i'll be discarding the width
[dataLabel sizeToFit];
//set the new frame (initial, but with the computed height)
dataLabel.frame = CGRectMake(initialLabelRect.origin.x, initialLabelRect.origin.y, initialLabelRect.size.width, dataLabel.frame.size.height);

//add and release 
[superview addSubview:dataLabel];
[dataLabel release];
```

So, the issue persists, but, for the time being... I'm replacing the code occurrences for this approach.

If someone come up with a clue about what happened, please let me know. I'm guessing it+s a bug on sizeWithFont method... but is always easier to blame on the SDK when we can't understand... :)

Thank you all. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a difference in what sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: will return depending on which architecture your code is running on.  I've used the function to calculate the height of strings I want to display in UILabels in UITableViewCells so that I can calculate the final height of the cell.  I was getting one size on my iPhone 4, and a tester was getting big large cells on their iPod (old armv6 device).

The solution was posted here: [Is there a way to compile for ARM rather than Thumb in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390606/is-there-a-way-to-compile-for-arm-rather-than-thumb-in-xcode-4)

I'm sure the optimization fix described below works as well, but disabling thumb might allow you to maintain your optimization settings?  I don't know, you'd have to test this.