# Ad hoc VS Build application behavior

Tags: iphone, compilation, xcode4.2, adhoc

I have developed a simple app that contains a UITableView that displays data, and when you click on a row, it displays an details page.

If I compile my apps and put it on my iPhone 3G, it works perfectly as expected. The problem occurs when I create an ad hoc of my apps. When installed on my same iPhone 3G, graphical glitches occur everywhere in my detailled page. I really don't know where to start looking to understand this.

Anyone ever had this problem? 
Thanks.

- EDIT *

A precision, I'm using XCode 4.2 (Apple LLVM Compiler)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is XCode archive acting different than XCode build/run on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813711/why-is-xcode-archive-acting-different-than-xcode-build-run-on-iphone)

Comment: Indeed that is the same question, thanks for the info ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to turn off compiler optimizations.

Something is going wrong with UI on old iOS 3.x and 4.x ARMv6 devices when compiling a release build. I have no idea why, but turning off compiler optimizations will help.

Turning off Thumb may also help you with this issue, you can go to your build settings and mouse over the "Other C Flags" option. Click on the little plus button that appears to the right of this option and add a condition for the ARMv6 architecture. Do this again to create one for the ARMv7 architecture. Under the ARMv6 architecture, add the extra compiler flag of `-mno-thumb`.

[image: Thumb turned off for ARMv6]

Comment: I have a question, I'm using XCode 4.2, so the compilation is now done with Apple LLVM Compiler. I guess this setting won't work for this compiler.