# testflight (or ad hoc) vs cable install

Tags: ios, xcode, build, adhoc

I am developing an application that draws a graphic.
When I install it directly from xcode on the device (iPhone 5), it runs perfectly. If I archive it and try to install on the same device from ad hoc or testflight, everything runs perfect, except for the graphic, tha doesn't draw.

I am using Xcode 6.3. The device runs IOS 8.3.

Thank you.

EDIT - SOLUTION

I found this answer: [Ad hoc VS Build application behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908120/ad-hoc-vs-build-application-behavior) .
I was afraid that the version of xcode treated on this post (4.2) was older and the solution wouldn't work. Well, it worked for xcode 6.3. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What process are you using to draw the graphics? Does it work in the simulator?

Comment: When you installing via xcode - it's in a Debug mode. When you installing via Adhoh - it's a Release mode. Need find difference between Debug-Release modes.

Comment: I am using simple Uiviews to draw the graphics and it works perfectly on simulator. The only problem is in the archive, so I believe when I upload to App Store it will go with the wrong behavior.