# App Store Binary runs choppy compared to Running with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app in the App Store that is running very choppy when I download it from the App Store but when I run it form Xcode it runs fine.  Has anyone run into this before?  Any solutions to fix this?

Comment: Did you run it in the simulator or on your device from Xcode?

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813711/why-is-xcode-archive-acting-different-than-xcode-build-run-on-iphone?rq=1, have you tried turning off compiler optimizations?

Comment: I dont know exactly when this started happening because I usually run the app on my main device with the version form Xcode, but this app has been in the App Store for over 2 years without this issue.  Only recently has it become choppy.  So to answer the first question, yes I have run it in the simulator without issues.

Comment: I do have the optimizations turned off for debug and they are set to Fastest, Smallest [-Os] for both release and distribution.  I am running the app with the release version in Xcode.