# Third party SDK returns incorrect value after notarizing my App

Tags: cocoa, notarize

I'm facing a pretty weird issue. I have a function GetInfoA() which returns the value processed from the SDK API. Everything is normal until the app is notarized from Xcode. The value returned from GetInfoA() will be incorrect. I have NO idea why this happened because all the other functions from the API return the correct value, which means the SDK is working properly... right?
Could anyone give me a hint on how to debug it? I'm clueless. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update:
I found this issue may not be related to notarization. The same issue is found if the App is "archived" from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I found this is not notarization-related. The "archived" app has this issue and could be solved by turning off the optimization. Thanx to [Why is XCode archive acting different than XCode build/run on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813711/why-is-xcode-archive-acting-different-than-xcode-build-run-on-iphone)