# Assignment causes unexpected results with specific iOS configurations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm getting some really weird behavior in my iOS app. It works fine on the simulator and on new hardware, but when I test it with the Release configuration on an older-gen iPod Touch (software version 4.2.1) it doesn't work properly. This is my code to drag the object (a UIView subclass):

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

// Set the correct center when touched 
touchPoint.x -= deltaX;
touchPoint.y -= deltaY;

NSLog(@"Touch moved1: %f %f, %f %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, self.center.x, self.center.y);
self.center = touchPoint;
NSLog(@"Touch moved2: %f %f, %f %f\n", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, self.center.x, self.center.y);
}
```

This is the resulting log output:

```
Touch moved1: -43.000000 45.000000, 45.000000 41.000000
Touch moved2: 45.000000 45.000000, 45.000000 41.000000
Touch moved1: -44.000000 45.000000, 45.000000 41.000000
Touch moved2: 45.000000 45.000000, 45.000000 41.000000
```

As you can see, somehow the assignment `self.center = touchPoint` changes the value of `touchPoint`. Instead of following your finger as you drag, the x and y values `touchPoint` become equal to the `touchPoint.y`, which contrains the movement to that diagonal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the device an ARM6 device?

There is a known bug in the ARM6 code generation in some versions of Xcode that causes problems like this. Try turning on the -mno-thumb option in the "other c flags" build setting section and see if it helps. If so, you can conditionally turn it on for ARM6 builds only.

See: [This item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390606/is-there-a-way-to-compile-for-arm-rather-than-thumb-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Fixed the issue perfectly. Thanks!