# How to add -mthumb to Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Reading through the [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20140720104744/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html) I saw this paragraph:

> Build your program using the Thumb option. Adding the -mthumb compiler
>   flag can reduce the size of your code by up to 35%. However, if your
>   app contains floating-point–intensive code modules and you are
>   building your app for ARMv6, you should disable the Thumb option. If
>   you are building your code for ARMv7, you should leave Thumb enabled.

Where do I put the flag **-mthumb** on Xcode? I'am using Xcode 4.4.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390606/is-there-a-way-to-compile-for-arm-rather-than-thumb-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the assembler output, I believe Thumb generation is the default in clang when building for armv7. You can turn it off using `-mno-thumb`.

Comment: I could not find this option, can you be more specific?

Comment: You can pass arbitrary compiler flags in "Other C Flags." You can set individual file options in the Build Phases>Compile Sources section. Turning off thumb generation is pretty rare, though I have had to do it before in C++ code that broke the compiler.